# Site lists no longer displayed as text?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

As of yesterday, the lists of sites (under "All Questions", "Science", &c) are no longer displayed as text lists for me.  Instead, they're arrayed on a grid, with icons & graphics that obscure a lot of the text, making them nearly unreadable.  How can I get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 5):

That's because you wanted to sort the sites [as list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list):

> [image: click the list icon]

Comment: Thanks.  For the developers, wouldn't it be much easier for everyone if you would put some words there so people would have a hope in hell of knowing what that bunch of squiggly lines means?  It'd also be nice to have an option to sort alphabetically.

Comment: @jamesqf As with a lot of things around Stack sites - hover over the icon for more info ;)

Comment: @nicael: No, I meant something like "Show as text list" and "Show as icon grid".  As for the tooltips, they may appear in whatever browser you're using, but they don't in mine (Opera).  And of course I'd have to realize that the little square actually did something, rather than being just another decoration, before I'd hover over it :-)

Comment: @jamesqf So you can post a feature-request :) Can't do anything with it, not an employee.